# Как правильно сгенерировать ts/js классы на основе proto-файла?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, typescript, grpc

Я пытаюсь сделать простой чат с помощью gRPC. В качестве клиента использую React-приложение.
У меня есть такой proto-файл:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package chat;

service Messaging {
  rpc SendMessage (stream MyMessage) returns (stream MyMessage) {};
}
 
message MyMessage {
  string name = 1;
  string message = 2;
}
```

Я пытаюсь на его основе сгенерировать ts/js файлы с помощью следующей команды:

```
protoc -I. proto/*.proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs:./src --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcwebtext:./src
```

Генерируется вот такой класс клиента:

```
import * as grpcWeb from 'grpc-web';

import * as proto_chat_pb from '../proto/chat_pb';


export class MessagingClient {
  client_: grpcWeb.AbstractClientBase;
  hostname_: string;
  credentials_: null | { [index: string]: string; };
  options_: null | { [index: string]: any; };

  constructor (hostname: string,
               credentials?: null | { [index: string]: string; },
               options?: null | { [index: string]: any; }) {
    if (!options) options = {};
    if (!credentials) credentials = {};
    options['format'] = 'text';

    this.client_ = new grpcWeb.GrpcWebClientBase(options);
    this.hostname_ = hostname.replace(/\/+$/, '');
    this.credentials_ = credentials;
    this.options_ = options;
  }
}
```

То есть в этом клиента нет моего метода SendMessage. При этом, я попробовал тем же способом сгенерировать вот такой proto-файл:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message EchoRequest {
  string message = 1;
}

message EchoResponse {
  string message = 1;
}

service EchoService {
  rpc Echo(EchoRequest) returns (EchoResponse);
}
```

И для этого proto-файла все сгенерировалось правильно. То есть, как я понимаю, проблема в том, что мой метод SendMessage передает и принимает поток, но я не нашел, как решить эту проблему.
Protoc у меня установлен - версия 3.20.0

Также установлены пакеты:

```
"google-protobuf": "^3.21.2",
"grpc-web": "^1.4.2",
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сгенерировать класс клиента, чтобы в нем был метод SendMessage? Заранее благодарю.

На всякий случай, выложил проект на gitHub. Ссылка: https://github.com/ByMyKolaps/gRPC.Chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, что библиотека grpc-web не поддерживает двунаправленную потоковую передачу